# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (F(x+a)-F(x))dx=a$ for all $a>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

This is a qualifying exam problem. Suppose $F$ is a distribution function of a Borel measure $\mu$ with $\mu (\Bbb R)=1$. Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (F(x+a)-F(x))dx=a$ for all $a>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fubini. Or rather Tonelli. We have $$F(x+a)-F(x)=\mu([x,x+a)).$$And $$\int\mu([x,x+a))dx
=\int\int\chi_{[x,x+a)}(t)\,d\mu(t)dx
=\int\int\chi_{[x,x+a)}(t)\,dxd\mu(t)=\int a\,d\mu=a.$$

Answer (score 4):

By Fubini's theorem,
\begin{align*}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty(F(x + a) - F(x)) dx \\
= & \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int_{-\infty}^{x + a}\mu(dt) - \int_{-\infty}^x\mu(dt)\right]dx \\
= & \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty I_{(x, x + a]}(t)\mu(dt)\right]dx \\
= & \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty I_{(x, x + a]}(t)dx\right]\mu(dt) \\ 
= & \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\int_{t - a}^{t} 1 dx\right]\mu(dt) \\ 
= & a\int_\mathbb{R} \mu(dt) \\
= & a.
\end{align*}

Comment: Great! Thanks!!